# The sequence $b_n=pa_n+qa_{n+1}$, where $|p|<q$, is convergent. Prove that $a_n$ converges. If $|p|\geq q > 0$ show that $a_n$ need not converge.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $a_n$ be a given sequence such that the sequence $b_n=pa_n+qa_{n+1}$, where $|p|<q$, is convergent.  Prove that $a_n$ converges.  If $|p|\geq q > 0$ show that $a_n$ need not converge.

I post my attempt below, its missing some steps because I'm very slow at latex - sorry.  I hope you can understand what I am trying to do.  I want to know if its valid to keep replacing with the inequality as I suggested.

\begin{align*}
|a_n-a_m|&=\biggl\lvert \frac{b_n-b_m + q(a_{m+1}-a_{n+1})}{p} \biggr\rvert\\
&\leq \biggl\lvert \frac{b_n-b_m}{p} \biggr\rvert + \biggl\lvert \frac{q}{p} \biggr\rvert \biggl\lvert (a_{m+1}-a_{n+1}) \biggr\rvert \\
\end{align*}

Now if we keep replacing $|a_{m+1}-a_{n+1}|$ with the RHS of the inequality infintely many times and choose $N$ such that for all $n,m>N$, $|b_n-b_m|<e$ for any $e>0$.  Note that since $|p|<q$ it follows that $|p/q|<1$. We have:

\begin{align*}
|a_n-a_m|& \leq \biggl\lvert \frac{e}{p} \biggr\rvert \biggl\lvert [1+p/q+(p/q)^2...]\biggr\rvert \\
|a_n-a_m|& \leq \biggl\lvert \frac{e}{p} \biggr\rvert \biggl\lvert (\frac{1}{1-p/q}) \biggr\rvert \\
\end{align*}

Now since $e$ is arbitary and p and q are constants, it follows that we can find some $N$ such that for all $n,m>N$, $|a_n-a_m|<e$.  But if $|p|>q$ then the geometric series diverges, and no matter what $N$ is chosen, $|a_n-a_m|<e$ for any $e$ is impossible.

Comment: The first part looks fine. However, the second part is not since you only showed that $|a_n-a_m|$ is bounded above by a divergent sequence. This is not enough (think the case $a_n=a_m$).

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry i'm not sure what parts you are referring to.  Are you saying that the proof that $a_n$ converges is okay but the part for $|p|>q$ is not?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @QuangHoang Which is true:  if $|p|>q$ then $a_n$ must diverge, or if $|p|>q$ then $a_n$ may or may not diverge?  Also why do you say that I proved that it is bounded above?  I thought for the second part I showed that the distance is not bounded no matter what N is chosen.  Sorry not following.

Comment: Note that $$a_n=\frac1qb_{n-1}-\frac{p}qa_{n-1}=\frac1qb_{n-1}-\frac{p}{q^2}b_{n-2}+\frac{p^2}{q^2}a_{n-2}$$ hence $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{p^{k-1}}{q^k}b_{n-k}+(-1)^n\frac{p^n}{q^n}a_0$$ and use the $\epsilon$-$N$ characterization of the convergence of $(b_n)$ and the fact that $$\left|\frac{p}q\right|<1$$